# Can python snippets be placed in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I would like to read the "version" from a file

```
# The "version" is no longer taken from here but rather from the "version" file
version = "0.3.13"    # This should be read from a file..
```

How can this be done inside the *pyproject.toml* .. or is that not possible?  If not possible is there a way to read the contents from a file into a variable inside the *pyproject.toml*?  Ultimately is that file just static ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toml is a static file format. See https://toml.io So there is no way to read content from a different place.

Because you are talking about `pyproject.toml` and `version` I guess your goal is to have single source of truth for the version number of your python project, so that it can be used during runtime. If so the correct way to do it, to have the version in the `pyproject.toml`. Once the project is installed  you can use [importlib.metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) to get the version number in your program:

```py
import importlib.metadata


version = importlib.metadata.version("my-package")
```

Comment: ok..  I was hoping to avoid the churn of git PR/commits to the `pyproject.toml` but that's not possible apparently . btw there is a versioning issue as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414497/the-poetry-script-from-a-pip-installed-package-has-a-requirement-parse-with-the