# The poetry script from a pip-installed package has a Requirement.parse with the wrong version

Tags: python, python-poetry

The package *version* for our app is 0.3.19 in both  *setup.py* and in *pyproject.toml* since we use *poetry*.  Everything works for publishing - it is visible in artifactory and can be `pip install`'ed.

But then when running a script associated with it

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_app = "my_app.my_app:main"
```

Then there is the error:

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (hercl 0.3.19 (~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
, Requirement.parse('my_app==0.3.7'))
```

There is NO reference to 0.3.7 anywhere in any file in the root of this project.  Only 0.3.19. So where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a corruption in the `pyenv` environments on my local machine. There were old versions of the `my_app` hanging around in the `site_packages`.   I nuked `pyenv`, installed `conda` and created a `virtualenv` using `conda` and the app `pip install`'s and works fine now